# Compare two column height Bootstrap / move div between column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to compare two column heights from same row in Bootstrap?

What I have developed is like this

Sample 1

[image]

Sample 2

[image]

So I developed one simple page that the info from the page is retrieved from the input value. The problem is the user can input the value dynamically just like from the image sample 1 and sample 2.

Sample 1 has an equal amount of information for left column and right column. However, sample 2 has unequal amount of the information.

So, what I would like to accomplish is whether there is a way to compare the column based on the height. If the left column has greater height than right column, I would like to move Contact div section from left column to right column. I tried to google it, but I don't get any solution regarding this problem.

Or is there other way to do it rather than compare the height of the column?

The page is developed by using Bootstrap.

Here is the code that I work on

```
<div class="first-head">
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 first-head-img">
          <img src="images/2.png" alt="2" data-sr='enter left, move 50px, over 0.5s'  />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 first-head-descr">
          <h1 data-sr='enter right, move 50px, over 0.5s' >Ahmad Farhan</h1>
          <p data-sr='enter right, move 50px, wait 0.2s, over 0.5s' ><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>farhan@yahoo.com</p>
          <p data-sr='enter right, move 50px, wait 0.4s,  over 0.5s' ><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i> +018 1234567</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="first-position">
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, wait 0.6s, over 0.5s' >Position Applied: Admin Executive</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">



        <div class="col-md-12 first-descr-objective">
          <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i> Objective

          <svg class="first-descr-objective-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="0" />
          </svg>

          <p>To obtain a position of Public Relations, editing or research that utilizes my communication, analytical, and writing skill.</p>
        </div>




        <div class="col-md-12 first-descr-skills">
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i> Skills

          <svg class="first-descr-skills-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="0"/>
          </svg>

          <h3>Human Relation & Communication</h3>
          <div class="progress-element">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-skills" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>- communicated in writing and by phone to many customers.<br/>- communicated in writing and by phone to many customers.</p>

          <h3>Administrative and Management</h3>
          <div class="progress-element">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-skills" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>- Gathering information to process customer account.<br/>- Organized billing to maintain timely account.<br/>- Improved training for incoming employees.</p>
        </div>




        <div class="col-md-12 first-descr-language">
          <i class="fa fa-language"></i> Language

          <svg class="first-descr-language-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="0"/>
          </svg>

          <p>English</p>
          <div class="progress-element-language">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-language" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>Bahasa Malaysia</p>
          <div class="progress-element-language">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-language" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>Mandarin</p>
          <div class="progress-element-language">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-language" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>




        <div class="col-md-12 first-descr-contact">
          <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact

          <svg class="first-descr-contact-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="0"/>
          </svg>

          <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +012 123 4567</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> farhan/myFacebookPage</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> farhan/MyTwiiterPage</p>
        </div>
      </div>






      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-12 first-descr-employment">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Employment

          <svg class="first-descr-employment-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="0"/>
          </svg>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 first-descr-employment-square-part">
          <svg class="first-square">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:1;stroke-opacity:1">
          </svg>
          <br/>
          <svg class="first-vr-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1000"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 first-descr-employment-year">
          <p>2015 - 2016</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 first-descr-employment-descr">
          <h3>Admin Officer <span>| Petaling Jaya</span></h3>
          <p class="subhead">Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <p>Are own entire former get should. Advantages boisterous day excelence boy. Out the fill between our two waiting wishing.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 first-descr-employment-square-part">
          <svg class="first-square">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:1;stroke-opacity:1">
          </svg>
          <br/>
          <svg class="first-vr-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1000"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 first-descr-employment-year">
          <p>2014 - 2015</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 first-descr-employment-descr">
          <h3>Admin Clerk <span>| Bangsar</span></h3>
          <p class="subhead">Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <p>Are own entire former get should. Advantages boisterous day excelence boy. Out the fill between our two waiting wishing.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 first-descr-employment-square-part">
          <svg class="first-square">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:1;stroke-opacity:1">
          </svg>
          <br/>
          <svg class="first-vr-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1000"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 first-descr-employment-year">
          <p>2013 - 2014</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 first-descr-employment-descr">
          <h3>Call Operator <span>| Bangsar</span></h3>
          <p class="subhead">Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <p>Are own entire former get should. Advantages boisterous day excelence boy. Out the fill between our two waiting wishing.</p>
        </div>




        <div class="col-md-12 first-descr-education">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Education

          <svg class="first-descr-education-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="0"/>
          </svg>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 first-descr-education-vr-part">
          <svg class="first-education-vr-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1000"/>
          </svg>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 first-descr-education-square-part">
          <svg class="first-square">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:1;stroke-opacity:1">
          </svg>
          <br/>
          <svg class="first-vr-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1000"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 first-descr-education-year">
          <p>2012 - 2013</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 first-descr-education-descr">
          <h3>Universiti Tun Hussien Onn (UTHM) <span>| Johor</span></h3>
          <p class="subhead">Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <p>Are own entire former get should. Advantages boisterous day excelence boy. Out the fill between our two waiting wishing.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 first-descr-education-square-part first-descr-education-square-se">
          <svg class="first-square">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:1;stroke-opacity:1">
          </svg>
          <br/>
          <svg class="first-vr-line">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1000"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 first-descr-education-year">
          <p>2011 - 2012</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 first-descr-education-descr">
          <h3>Pahang Matericulation Technical College <span>| Pahang</span></h3>
          <p class="subhead">Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <p>Are own entire former get should. Advantages boisterous day excelence boy. Out the fill between our two waiting wishing.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-1 first-descr-education-square-part first-descr-education-square-part-2">
          <svg class="first-square">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:1;stroke-opacity:1">
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 first-descr-education-year">
          <p>2010 - 2011</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 first-descr-education-descr">
          <h3>Sekolah Menengah Teknik Kuala Krai <span>| Kelantan</span></h3>
          <p class="subhead">Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <p>Are own entire former get should. Advantages boisterous day excelence boy. Out the fill between our two waiting wishing.</p>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for asking this.

I'm slightly unsure as to your intention, however, if you mean to match the heights of your divs, that is easily done through a JQuery plugin called ['matchheight'](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/). It can be found here, please see below for syntax.

`$(function() {
    $('.item').matchHeight(options);
});`

the options parameter is optional (I think that made sense), but see below for the options available

The default options are:

```
byRow: true,
property: 'height',
target: null,
remove: false
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to make both column have almost/similar content height. If you see sample 2, the blank part on right column (white part after education section) is quite big if we compare to sample 1 that left column only has small blank part. So for case on sample 2, I want to move the the contact section on left left to the right column to make both column has similar height of the content.

Comment: I see, if you want to make the column **content** similar heights, I would suggest you just modify and tweak the column widths till they're similar. If you add this to a jsfiddle project or upload to git (then comment with URL of either) I'll attempt to fix it for you. Otherwise just modify the bootstrap columns to resize and force the text into a different size container, and thus making the content thinner/wider